# Entity Framework not updating data in database with update

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I am trying to insert/update data into a table using Entity Framework 4.1 from an Edit action in my MVC3 controller with the following code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(UserDetailsForm form)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            UserProfile up = cpctx.UserProfiles.Where(w => w.UserName.Equals(form.email)).SingleOrDefault();
            if (up == null)
            {
                up = new UserProfile();
                up.UserName = form.email;
                up.FirstName = form.FirstName;
                up.LastName = form.LastName; 
                ctx.UserProfiles.Add(up);
            }
            else
            {
                up.FirstName = form.FirstName;
                up.LastName = form.LastName; 
                cpctx.Entry(up).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }



            ctx.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(form);
    }
    catch
    {
        return View(form);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine for an new record and I get a new row in the database, my problem occurs when updating.  The code executes without any exceptions and I can see the values in `up` correctly in the watch window, however, when `ctx.SavesChanges()` is executed the database is not updated.

Any help in resolving this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you forget cpctx.SaveChanges() ?

Comment: danihp, thank you sooo much you are correct, I had a duplication of my context further up in the code and was calling that for the save. I've been throwing this around for over an hour and feel ashamed that it was such a fundamental mistake on my behalf

Comment: Your code uses two different contexts but calls save changes only for one of them (the one used for insertion).